# when running rails s after switching from my server to my employers server, I am getting these errors:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

`rails s` worked on my server and after switching servers, I got this error when running `rails s`. What could be causing this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):       
4: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>' 
3: from bin/rails:3:in `load'                     
2: from /home/directoryName1/directoryName2/directoryName3/bin/spring:8:in `<top (required)>' 
1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require' /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 0):

It says that `bundler` library cannot be found. Try running `gem install bundler` to install [Bundler](https://bundler.io), then `bundle install` to get your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

> What could be causing this?

Bundler is not found, but it could also be spring. You can try to stop spring with

```
bin/spring stop
```